# which .jar file has javax.xml.stream.*?

Tags: java, xml, stax

I have problems again with my Mac running Java 1.5.... where do I get a .jar file that has javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory ? I want to use StAX but don't know how to get it set up right.

---

I can't seem to get this setup. I've now downloaded jaxp-api.jar, jsr173_1.0_api.jar, sjsxp.jar, stax-api-1.0.1.jar, stax2-api-3.0.1.jar, and woodstox-core-asl-4.0.5.jar; put them all into my java/lib/ext directory, made sure they're on my eclipse build path, removed the Mac com.apple.quarantine extended attribute, did a "chmod a+x" on the .jar files, and I still get the following error trying to `import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;`

> Access restriction: The type
>   XMLInputFactory is not accessible due
>   to restriction on required library
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home/lib/ext/jsr173_1.0_api.jar

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

StAX is not a part of Java 5; you'll find it in [Java 6](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html), however.
For Java 5, you'll need to download a StAX implementation and place it in the classpath.

[Woodstox](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/) is one such implementation. You could also use the [Sun Java StAX XML processor](http://sjsxp.java.net/), which has made its way into Java SE 6.

Unless I'm mistaken, both of these implementations will eventually use the **jsr173_api.jar**, where you'll find the javax.xml.stream package.

**Update:**

The Woodstox documentation would refer you to download the [StAX 1.0.1 API jar](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/stax-api-1.0.1.jar) (required when you use the standard StAX API); the StAX2 API jar in Woodstox will not contain the javax.xml.stream package (although you'll need both JARs at runtime). The Sun implementation depends on the [stax-utils](https://stax-utils.dev.java.net/) project.

**Update 2**

*Installing JSXP*

The download files area of SJSXP looks a bit weird, in that you have a class file, instead of build JARs. However, all that is needed to obtain the SJSXP JAR, is to execute the class file, which unpacks the distribution.

*Getting the StAX API JAR*

The StAX API jar (jsr173_api.jar or the like) can be obtained from the StAX utilities project. It needs to be in the same directory as the sjsxp jar.

*Using the JARs in Eclipse*

It is not necessary to add the JARs to lib/ext of the JDK. It is enough to add the two JARs to the Build Path of the project.

Comment: OK I am trying to deal with this calmly and avoid screaming. I have downloaded SJSXP and put both sjsxp.jar and jsr173_1.0_api.jar into the java /lib/ext directory, but Eclipse refuses to realize there's a javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory in the classpath >:( help!

Comment: Are you sure Eclipse is using the same JRE that you are expecting it to? Putting stuff in lib/ext is a bit fragile. It should be fine on the standard classpath.

Comment: Updated the answer to indicate what needs to be done to include SJSXP & JSR 173 API in Eclipse. Tested on the SJSXP example (cursor.CursorParse example).

Answer (score 19):

Can I point you to [findjar.com](http://www.findjar.com), which allows you to enter a classname and determine which jar is required.

e.g. [XMLInputFactory](http://www.findjar.com/class/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html) yields

```
jsr173_1.0_api.jar
jsr173_api.jar
stax-api-1.0.1.jar
stax-api-1.0.1.jar
stax-api-1.0.jar
groovysoap-all-jsr06-0.1.jar
```

Comment: indeed, findjar is an invaluable tool, have used it in the past with JavaEE and IBM's WebSphere stuff to find where some class was that was poorly documented