# Minimum JDK for AXIS2?

Tags: dependencies, apache-axis

I am trying to add AXIS2 to an old legacy system that is tied to JDK 1.5.  I am getting errors like:

```
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamException
       at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java:50)
       ...
```

Seems clear enough, no?  So I did some research, and here's what I found:

- According to "System Requirements"
  (http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/installationguide.html#requirements),
  AXIS2 should be OK with JDK 1.5.
- However, looking at the source code,
  I see many references to XMLStreamException.  This class is not
  available until JDK 1.6
  (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamException.html).

I am stumped.  The documentation says it should work, but the reality is otherwise.  Am I missing something?  Is the latest AXIS2 release compatible with JDK 1.5?  If not, which version is?  Or have I gone completely off script?

Thanks,
DC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before Java 6, StAX wasn't part of the JRE. You can still use it by providing your own StaX implementation, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319264/which-jar-file-has-javax-xml-stream).

Comment: Well that was moderately painful, but correct.  Thanks for your help.